# phpmyadmin のダウンロードができない

Tags: phpmyadmin

下記の通り wget コマンドを実行してもエラーになってしまいます。なぜでしょうか？

**実行したコマンド**

```
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmyadmin/files/phpMyAdmin/4.4.14/phpMyAdmin-4.4.14-all-languages.tar.gz
```

**エラーメッセージ**

```
    --2015-08-27 07:21:27--  http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmyadmin/files/phpMyAdmin/4.4.14/phpMyAdmin-4.4.14-all-languages.tar.gz
    Resolving sourceforge.net (sourceforge.net)... 216.34.181.60
    Connecting to sourceforge.net (sourceforge.net)|216.34.181.60|:80... connected.
    HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
    2015-08-27 07:21:27 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Comment: ダウンロードサイトが変更になった様ですね。https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/

Answer (score 3):

404 Not Found なので、指定のアドレスにファイルが存在しないことを意味しています。
変更されたアドレスを指定したこちらのコマンドでお試しください。

wget https://files.phpmyadmin.net/phpMyAdmin/4.4.14/phpMyAdmin-4.4.14-all-languages.tar.gz